# Making HTTP GET request that target a collection of instances in DjangoRESTFUL

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework

I started with checking if the serializer works as i expected but it didn't show any output after running the code.

```
from datetime import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.six import BytesIO
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from toys.models import Toy
from toys.serializers import ToySerializer




toy_release_date = timezone.make_aware(datetime.now(),
 timezone.get_current_timezone())
toy1 = Toy(name='Snoopy talking action figure',
 description='Snoopy spearks five languages')
toy1,save()
toy2 = Toy(name='Hawaiian Barbie', 
description= 'Barbie loves Hawaii',
 release_date="")
toy2.save()


print(toy1.pk)
print(toy1.name)
print(toy1.created)
print(toy1.was_inclded_in_home)
print(toy2.pk)
print(toy2.name)
print(toy2.created)
print(toy2.was_included_in_home)



serializer_for_toy1 = ToySerializer(toy1)
print(serializer_for_toy1.data)

serializer_for_toy2 = ToySerializer(toy2)
print(serializer_for_toy2.data)


json_renderer = JSONRenderer()
toy1_rendered_into_json = jason_renderer.render(serializer_for_toy1.data)
toy2_rendered_into_json = json_renderer.render(serializer_for_toy2.data)
print(toy1_rendered_into_json)
print(toy2_rendered_into_json)


json_string_for_new_toy = '{"name":"Clash Royale play set","descriptions":"6 figures from Clash Royele"}'
json_bytes_for_new_toy = bytes(json_string_for_new_toy, encoding="UTF-8")
stream_for_new_toy = BytesOI(json_bytes_for_new_toy)
parser = JSONParser()
parsed_new_toy =parser.parse(stream_for_new_toy)
print(parsed_new_toy)

new_toy_serializer = ToySerializer(data=parsed_new_toy)
if new_toy_serializer.is_valid():
    toy3 = new_toy_serializer.save()
    print(toy3.name)
```

but then i had started with creating my Django views combined with serializer classes.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from rest_framework import status
from toys.models import Toy
from toys.serializers import ToySerializer 


class JSONResponse(HttpResponse):
    def __init__(self, data, **kwargs):
        content = JSONRenderer().render(data)
        kwargs['content_type'] ='application/json'
        super(JSONResponse, self).__init__(content, **kwargs)


@csrf_exempt
def toy_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        toys = Toy.objects.all()
        toys_serializer = ToySerializer(toys, many=True)
        return JSONResponse(toys_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        toy_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        toys_serializer = ToySerializer(data=toy_data)
        if toys_serializer.is_valid():
            toys_serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(toy_serializer.data, \
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return JSONResponse(toy_serializer.errors, \
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


@csrf_exempt
def toy_detail(request, pk):
    try:
        toy = Toy.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Toy.DoesNotExist:
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    if request.method == 'GET':
        toy_serializer = ToySerializer(toy)
        return JSONResponse(toy_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'PUT':
        toy_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        toy_serializer = ToySerializer(toy, data=toy_data)
        if toy_serializer.is_valid():
            toy_serializer.save()
            return JSONResponse(toy_serializer.data)
        return JSONResponse(toy_serializer.errors, \
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    elif request.method == 'DELETE' :
        toy.delete()
        return HttpResponse(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Here is my serializer.py content but after I make a request to HTTP doesn't display the content in this serializer.py.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from toys.models import Toy

class ToySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    pk = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=250)
    release_date = serializers.DateTimeField()
    toy_category = serializers.CharField(max_length=200)
    was_included_in_home = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)

    def create(self,validated_data):
        return Toy.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.name = validated_data.get('name',instance.name)
        instance.description = validated_data.get('description', instance.description)
        instance.release_date = validated_data.get('release_date',instance.release_date)
        instance.toy_category = validated_data.get('toy_category',instance.toy_category)
        instance.was_included_in_home = validated_data.get('was_included_in_home',instance.was_included_in_home)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```

after creating my view and tried making an HTTP GET request with curl, I get no output of the JSONResponse but it only displays an empty dictionary (square bracket, [] )which I expected it to display the content in the serializer.py file and I wonder what's wrong with my codes. Here is the code to make the HTTP request.

```
curl -x GET localhost:8000/toys/

#With this code it shows only the header without the JSON response and an empty [].
curl -ix GET localhost:8000/toys/
```

```
from datetime import datetime 
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.six import BytesIO
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer
from rest_framework.parsers import JSONParser
from toys.models import Toy
from toys.serializers import ToySerializer




toy_release_date = timezone.make_aware(datetime.now(),
 timezone.get_current_timezone())
toy1 = Toy(name='Snoopy talking action figure',
 description='Snoopy spearks five languages')
toy1,save()
toy2 = Toy(name='Hawaiian Barbie', 
description= 'Barbie loves Hawaii',
 release_date="")
toy2.save()


print(toy1.pk)
print(toy1.name)
print(toy1.created)
print(toy1.was_inclded_in_home)
print(toy2.pk)
print(toy2.name)
print(toy2.created)
print(toy2.was_included_in_home)



serializer_for_toy1 = ToySerializer(toy1)
print(serializer_for_toy1.data)

serializer_for_toy2 = ToySerializer(toy2)
print(serializer_for_toy2.data)


json_renderer = JSONRenderer()
toy1_rendered_into_json = jason_renderer.render(serializer_for_toy1.data)
toy2_rendered_into_json = json_renderer.render(serializer_for_toy2.data)
print(toy1_rendered_into_json)
print(toy2_rendered_into_json)


json_string_for_new_toy = '{"name":"Clash Royale play set","descriptions":"6 figures from Clash Royele"}'
json_bytes_for_new_toy = bytes(json_string_for_new_toy, encoding="UTF-8")
stream_for_new_toy = BytesOI(json_bytes_for_new_toy)
parser = JSONParser()
parsed_new_toy =parser.parse(stream_for_new_toy)
print(parsed_new_toy)

new_toy_serializer = ToySerializer(data=parsed_new_toy)
if new_toy_serializer.is_valid():
    toy3 = new_toy_serializer.save()
    print(toy3.name)
```

Comment: You should debug it and find out at which point an empty json list is returned.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using DRF then its better to follow their documentation.

As it stated in [**`documentation`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/):

> REST framework also allows you to work with regular function based views. It provides a set of simple decorators that wrap your function based views to ensure they receive an instance of Request (rather than the usual Django HttpRequest) and allows them to return a Response (instead of a Django HttpResponse), and allow you to configure how the request is processed.

So you need to wrap your function with [**`api_view`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#api_view) decorator and return [**`Response`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/responses/#response) from the function. For example in your case:

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Respons

@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def toy_list(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        toys = Toy.objects.all()
        toys_serializer = ToySerializer(toys, many=True)
        return Response(toys_serializer.data)

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        toys_serializer = ToySerializer(data=toy_data)
        if toys_serializer.is_valid():
            toys_serializer.save()
            return Response(toy_serializer.data, \
                status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(toy_serializer.errors, \
            status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: I just finished up wrapping your function to mine, but I am still getting the same empty dictionary, I had expected that it should display the JSON  file in the serializer.py when I make the request to HTTP.  the header shows HTTP/1.1 200 OK. but it should display the JSON file too. Thank you! I hope to find a solution soon.

Comment: Did you create any toy instance before?

Comment: Yes, I did and it's part of the code that I posted here, which is the serializer.py  if you can kindle look at it. Thank you